# reason for runtime error in my c program &?

Tags: runtime-error

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        main()
        {char *names[4];
        int i,a;
        printf("ënter the guests names\n");
               for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
               {
                 scanf("%s",names[i]);
               }
      char *yourname;
      printf("\nenter your name ");
      scanf("%c",yourname);
                    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
                       {a=strcmp(names[i],yourname);
                         if(a==0)
                         printf("\nwelcome");
                         break;
                       }
     if(a!=0)
     printf("\naccess denied");
     return 0;
     }
```

this is a program to check your entry in a show. first we give permitted names & then it asks your name ,it compares your name with the names in the guest list.

i m getting runtime error, plz tell me the correction.i want to use pointers to string so plz suggest correction in the existing program

when i run this program in devc++ after entering first name it gives program.exe stopped working.

Comment: You never initialize your `names` or `yourname` pointers so they will be garbage. Additionally your loop needs braces and please start indenting your code, it will make it much more readable.

Comment: You've dumped poorly formatted code without even telling us the error.  Please fix this to get an answer.

Comment: kindly make correction in my code

Comment: Kindly indent your code yourself because as-is it is impossible to read. You should also find your missing braces in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        char *names[4];
        int i,a;
        printf("ënter the guests names\n");
        for(i=0;i<=3;i++) {
                names[i] = (char*) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
            scanf("%s", names[i]);
        }
        char yourname[100];
        printf("\nenter your name ");
        scanf("%s",yourname);
        for(i=0;i<=3;i++) {
            a = strcmp(names[i], yourname);
            if (a == 0) break;
        }
        if (a==0)
            printf("\nwelcome");
        else printf("\naccess denied");

        for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
            free(names[i]);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have to be formated so we can give you a better answer.

Now, use gets to take your input, verify the guest match with your name inside the for loop, stop the loop when a match is found.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char names[4][20];
    int i = 0;
    int a = 0;
    printf("Enter guests names: \n");

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        gets(names[i]);
    }
    char yourname[20];
    printf("\n Enter your name ");
    gets(yourname);

    printf("\n Verify access right:");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {    
        a=strcmp(names[i], yourname);
        if(a==0)
        {
            printf("\n welcome");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n access denied");
        }
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

Although this looks like a homework assignment.